python imports are different on pi zero and pi twozero?
Having tested my python programs using SSH on two Pis from a PC, I wanted to autostart them (they will be a pump manager in the cellar and an upstairs monitor with a call to my mobile if something goes wrong). Much of the code is common and in one folder on each machine are the same 4 modules pump, monitor, common and parameters.
Starting with the bigger machine pizero2w I added an rc.local line pointed at the main 'pump' module that imports common and parameters.  "sudo python /home/pi/cellarpump.py &"  - perfect at reboot - lights flashing and relay firing. [I know I supposedly do not need the sudo - but it works!].
At this point no clever stuff with packaging or relative links - just "import * from common" in the same folder. [later in the program it reloads the parameters module on a timed basis so I can change the levels of water dynamically - or add in debug]
The same files on the pizero  - but the rc.local pointing at 'monitor' that imports the same common and parameters. Result - nothing. Debug prints show but not after the first import from common.  I have tried various permutations of the format of the rc.local record and 'sudo -u pi'.
All three pythons [there is a third program that looks after the other two that I can SSH on the phone]  are the same version 3.11.2. And I have never knowingly altered the python paths.
I prefer not to refactor the processes to packages and relative imports so I shall probably do the quick fix and buy another pi zero2.
My curiosity however is triggered - has anyone found this behaviour and had a thought on why? Is it perhaps a 32-bit thing?
As a by-the-way, the zero also has trouble executing the fstab for a NAS folder - whereas mount -a works fine - I am parking that as a race condition where the wifi is not ready because the zero is much slower :-(

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

A python import would explicitly fail if the python executable can't find the modules to be imported. So I don't think it's a python environment problem. You said that prints don't occur after the import. Is the program ending, or is blocking? I assume the latter, which  suggests that something in the python code is blocking or  taking a long time. Exactly what would depend on what the imported code is trying to do

Regarding your "by-the-way" question: You're right that mounts from /etc/fstab might give up before the wireless network is stable. I've used something like this in the past:
while true; do
        if findmnt -n /path/to/NFS/mount; then
                break # exit the while loop because it's mounted
        fi
        sleep 5
        mount /path/to/NFS/mount; # attempt to mount after waiting a bit
done

